# Replace a Dropdown Menu with a textbox in a responsive template

Tags: html, css, templates, responsive-design

I would like to replace a Dropodown Menu with a textbox in a search form.
The textbox must have the same size of the replaced Dropdown Menu.

Code of the form:

```
    <form action="#">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your key word">
                <div class="dropdown category-dropdown">                        
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="change-text">Job Location</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu category-change">
                        <li><a href="#">Location 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Location 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Location 3</a></li>
                    </ul>                               
                </div><!-- category-change -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">Search</button>
            </form>
```

Style:

```
.category-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px; 
  min-width: 200px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Anyway, here there is the link of the template:

https://demo.themeregion.com/jobs-updated/

Maybe it's a trivial question, but I'm new with the css technical since I'm a backend developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be something like this, in place of `<div class="dropdown category-dropdown">`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control category-textbox" placeholder="Type your key word">
```

Style:

```
.category-textbox{
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 20%;
}
```